# How to get latest episode from soundcloud episodes in php?

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, soundcloud

I am working on a [webpage](http://www.cpac.ca/en/testing-podcast/) in which I want to fetch the latest episode from the list of episodes. At this moment, I am fetching latest episode by changing the height in an iframe.

The code belonging to the page is:

```
<p> Latest Episode </p>

<iframe width="100%" height="150" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay"
        src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/755451006&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"></iframe>

<p> All Episodes </p>

<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay"
        src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/755451006&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"></iframe>
```

In order to fetch the latest episode, I have just changed the height. I am not sure if this is a long-term solution.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what modification I need to make in the code above so that I can fetch the latest episode from the list of episodes.

Comment: Have you looked into using soundclouds API? I think that might be a better option if you want to filter or have more control over data from their website. Maybe start here? [**soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide**](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide)

Comment: @NewToJS hi, if you check my answer. I solved it by changing the height of the iframe. Just wondering if its the proper way to do that ? Changing the height of the iframe.

Comment: @NewToJS Let me know your thoughts on that.